# When Loading Image Using BufferdImage and ImageIO it Clears my Whole Frame and Does Not Display Image

Tags: image, jframe, load, imageicon

I and making a program using basic GUI involving buttons, frames, and panels, and everything was fine until I tried to load an image from my project folder. When i add the line of code

```
   try{
         titleImage = ImageIO.read(new File("mouse_title_resize.png"));
       } 
    catch(Exception e){}
```

After I run the program my whole frame just becomes blank whereas before I had some JButtons on it.All the code I had before the try-catch line worked perfectly fine and I tested to see that the only thing that breaks it is this line of code. I receive no errors or anything and I have the image in my project folder and it seems that the image loaded fine, except it wont show up on the frame, and everything else on the frame disappears. I just don't understand why it clears my whole frame when i load the image.

Here is the full code:

This is the class that extends JFrame

package mouse.click.game;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Point;

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MouseClickGame extends JFrame {

```
//Constants to define the frame width and height including borders
public final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
public final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
//Dimension from Toolkit to be able to get width and height of screen
public Dimension sizeTool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
//Using sizeTool to get width of screen
public double xResolution = sizeTool.getWidth();
//Using sizeTool to get height of screen
public double yResolution = sizeTool.getHeight();
//Creating a point object that is defined as the center of the screen
public Point middleOfScreen = new Point((int) (xResolution / 2) - (FRAME_WIDTH / 2), (int) (yResolution / 2) - (FRAME_HEIGHT / 2));

public MouseClickGame() {
    super("WELCOME :D");
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocation(middleOfScreen);
    add(new MouseClickPanel());

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Calling constructor
    MouseClickGame mainClickGame = new MouseClickGame();

}
```

}

And here is the class that extends JPanel (these are the only two classes in my project)

package mouse.click.game;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.Box;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MouseClickPanel extends JPanel {

```
JButton buttonPlay = new JButton("Play");
JButton buttonContinue = new JButton("Continue");
JButton buttonOptions = new JButton("Options");
JButton buttonExit = new JButton("Exit");

BoxLayout boxLay = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

Dimension menuButtonSize = new Dimension(300, 30);
Dimension spacingBetweenButtons = new Dimension(0, 30);

BufferedImage titleImage;

public MouseClickPanel() {

    try {
        titleImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Justin\\Desktop\\mouse_title.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    setLayout(boxLay);
    add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(titleImage)));

    //Adding glue to force buttons away from top of panel
    add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    add(buttonPlay);
    //Vertical spacing between buttons
    add(Box.createRigidArea(spacingBetweenButtons));
    add(buttonContinue);

    add(Box.createRigidArea(spacingBetweenButtons));
    add(buttonOptions);

    add(Box.createRigidArea(spacingBetweenButtons));
    add(buttonExit);
    //Adding glue to force buttons away from bottom of panel
    add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    //Aligning all buttons to centered horizontally
    buttonPlay.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    buttonContinue.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    buttonOptions.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    buttonExit.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //Setting button sizes
    buttonPlay.setMaximumSize(menuButtonSize);
    buttonContinue.setMaximumSize(menuButtonSize);
    buttonOptions.setMaximumSize(menuButtonSize);
    buttonExit.setMaximumSize(menuButtonSize);

}
```

}

Literally if i get ride of the titleImage = and add(new JLabel) lines everything goes back to normal

Comment: Well, you're squelching the exception. Re-throw it with `throw e`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tired that but it didn't work (although I might have done it wrong) so i ended up making a separate project to test adding images and now it's giving me a nullpointerexception. I should of posted all the code first but this comment won't allow me to post anything extra. Do you think maybe you could show me how to properly import an image? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Wow literally the reason it wasn't showing up was because i called setVisble(true) too early. I can't believe it was something that simple. I guess that explains why one time everything would show up and it would be fine but then every time after nothing showed up.
So in my constructor I had

public class MouseClickGame extends JFrame {

```
public MouseClickGame() {
    super("WELCOME :D");
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(middleOfScreen);
    setVisible(true);
    add(new MouseClickPanel());


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Calling constructor
    MouseClickGame mainClickGame = new MouseClickGame();

}
```

}

when all I had to do was put the setVisble() after the add(newMouseClickPanel())

Thank you DavidS for your suggestions :D

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've just got the path wrong -- a common mistake. In that case, you *should* be getting an exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at jonathanrmiproject.MyProject.main(JonathanRmiProject.java:24)
```

This simple example works for me:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("myimage.jpg"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am using Netbeans IDE, and I have saved the image file to "C:\Users\David.Sharpe\MyProject\myimage.jpg".

I should add that if this is *not* the case, and you do have the correct path, then you need to post a more detailed question so that someone can help you. Include the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry I have posted the full code now I should have already done that. Thank you for your help so far. Also I tried both absolute an relative paths to the image but both reproduce the same results. Also your code in a blank project works perfectly fine it just doesn't work in my project. Thanks for your patience 
:D